# Seperate AWS IAM users resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have 5 IAM users under my root account, and I want to let each user to display only his resources not all the resources from the main account.

I need this for S3 service, I want each user to list his own buckets only. not all the buckets

I tried IAM policies but non of them worked for me.

I tried few instructions from the AWS documentation but it didn't work too

Comment: What you want isn't possible. You need to either separate them into completely separate AWS accounts, or build your own user interface on top of the AWS API that does what you want instead of letting them use the AWS web console.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create separate accounts for your users to access.

[Creating multiple sub accounts in IAM AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556831/creating-multiple-sub-accounts-in-iam-aws)